# Find A and B for a continuous random variable with the following density

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> Suppose $X$ is a (continuous) random variable with density
>   $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0 & \mbox{if }x ≤ 0
> \\[0.25ex]
> (A/x^2) & \mbox{if }0 < x < 1
> \\[0.25ex]
> (B/x^2) &\mbox{if }x ≥ 1
> \end{cases}$$
>
> for some real numbers $A$ and $B$. What are $A$ and $B$?

As a probability distribution, the density should be equal to 1

I tried integrating in terms of the intervals but it is not possible to integrate the $(A/x^2)$ as it doesn't converge in the interval $0$ to $1$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 0 is real number:-)

Comment: Does "x2" mean $x^2$?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right, if $A\ne 0$ then $\int_0^1\frac{A}{x^2}\,dx$ does not converge. So we must have $A=0$. Now finding $B$ is a routine integration.

Comment: I think I understand now. A has to equal to 0 because otherwise it wouldn't converge.

Then for B, I solve for the the integral from 1 to infinity and set that equal to 1. Since -1/infinity - (-1/1) is just 1, I get B=1

So A=0 and B=1?

Comment: Yes, $A=0$  and $B=1$.  (I would myself not write down an expression like \frac{-1}{\infty}$.)